# Increment number after X iterations

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to increment a number by one after X iterations. So for example in this case every 100 iterations I want to increment by 1. The length of the array is variable but we'll use an array of numbers 1-400 for this example:

```
let x = 0;
const arr = [
1,
2,
3,
...
400
];

arr.forEach((v, i) => {
 // if index is between 0 - 100 
 // then x = 0
 // if index is between 101-200
 // then x = 1
 // if index is between 201-300
 // then x = 2
 // so and and so forth..
})
```

It would ideally be nice if I didn't even need to keep track of `x` and I *think* I could possibly use `%` here but I'm not familiar enough with modulus to be able to write a formula that does this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: `if (i % 100 === 0) { x++}` and you could just use `Math.floor(i/100)`

Comment: Why use forEach if you only use the index ? Can't you do something like `const x = Math.floor(arr.length / 100)` ?

Comment: do you want to do anything inside the loop or just assign a value to x based on the array length?

Comment: @cmgchess yes for my use case I have an array of objects that I am going to want to assign a property to based on what `x` equals

Comment: Why is the first item 0-100 and the second one 101-200?